# Не отображается список товаров из хранилища Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Сегодня познакомился с библиотекой Redux. Пытался перекинуть из useState в redux store мой список товаров, но что-то пошло не так. В консоли ошибок нет, список товаров просто не рендерится на странице.

Создал папку redux, в ней:

### папка action, файл cards.js:

```
`export const setCards = (items) => ({
    type: 'SET_CARDS',
    payload: items,
})`
```

### папка reducers, файл cards.js:

```
    const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

const cards = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_CARDS":
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cards;
```

### всё та же папка reducers, файл index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import cards from "./cards";
import cart from "./cart";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cards,
    cart,
})

export default rootReducer
```

### и файл store.js в папке redux:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

window.store = store

export default store
```

### Файл App.js, где добавляю ссылку на браузерный API

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/items")
      .then(({ data }) => {
        dispatch(setCards(data.cards));
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: А вам точно сначала не надо делать `.then(res => res.json())`, перед тем как вызывать `.then(({ data }) => { dispatch(setCards(data.cards)); })`?

Comment: Хм, спасибо за совет, сегодня вечером попробую

Comment: Помогло то что я посоветовал?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое